# Bulk export shapefile layers to GeoJSON using QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, geojson

I have some `.shp` files that I would like to export them to a `GeoJSON` format.

I can use `Export > Save Feature As..` and use the `Save Vector Layer..` dialog to save them.

However, I have to do that one at a time. Is there a way to batch save them?

Note that I have tried the `Extract Selected Features` and the `Save vector features to file` dialogs, however, they seem to be exporting only a few bytes of data and not the entire shape geometry and metadata.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The [batch-vector-layer-saver](https://github.com/riccardoklinger/batch-vector-layer-saver) plugin did the trick.

From the README.md:

> #QGIS Batch Saver Plugin This plugin allow you to save multiple vector layers using a selection of file extensions in a configurable path.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).